# Quiero que un input radio aparezca como checked (tildado) cuando carga la página + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

He intentado de varias maneras y no puedo lograr esto. El archivo .js está bien linkeado (probé con un alert()). No tengo mensajes de error, directamente no hace nada la página. En qué estoy fallando?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.
HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="myId" name="myId">
```

JavaScript

```
function checkByDefault(){
    document.getElementById("myId").checked = true;
        
}

window.load = checkByDefault();
```

Comment: Para que funcione de la manera que lo estas haciendo el script debe ir despues del HTML.

Comment: Una opcion seria colocarle simplemente el atributo `checked` para que apesca asi, pero si quieres hacerlo con JS ya te dieron una respuesta

Comment: Ya tienes un par de buenas respuestas, pero te comento que no te funcionaba porque tienes `windows.load` en lugar de `window.onload` y, de todos modos no funcionaría, porque al incluir paréntesis `window.onload = checkByDefault();` la función se va a ejecutar inmediatamente, sin esperar a que se haya cargado la página; debería ser `window.onload = checkByDefault;`.  La recomendación es que sigas lo sugerido en alguna de las respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr eso podes usar [window.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) con el evento `DOMContentLoaded` o `load`

Pues la diferencia entre estos dos eventos es que el **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)**
se dispara apenas el documento HTML termina de cargar completamente (este evento no espera por hojas de estilos, images) mientras que el evento **[load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)** se dispara cuando todo el HTML es cargado incluyendo todas sus dependencias, hojas de estilos, imágenes.

espero que el código de abajo te sirva de guía! Saludos!

```js
function checkByDefault(){
    document.getElementById("myId").checked = true;
        
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkByDefault);
//window.addEventListener('load', checkByDefault);
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="myId" name="myId">
```

Comment: Se tendria que preguntar al OP si usar `DOMContentLoaded` o `load`

Comment: Gracias por consejo @JuanRivera.

Answer (score 0):

Debería de funcionarte, aunque lo correcto sería detectar cuando el contenido del documento haya cargado:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    

  });
```

Intenta con la función `setAttribute()`:

```
function checkByDefault(){
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute('checked','true');

}
```

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function checkByDefault(){
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute('checked','true');

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
  checkByDefault();
    
});
```

En caso de no quedar prueba poniendo checked en la propia etiqueta:

```
<input type="radio" id="myId" name="myId" checked>
```